# SQL query to update ave_cost for entire category column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table that needs to have (for every row) the average cost of that record and the average cost of the category in which it's in.

```
id      category   cost       num  ave_cost   ave_cost_category
15117012    15    357.00     420      0.85         0.85   
79030402    79    365.00     349      1.04         1.04  
90125402    90    351.20     439      0.80         0.828 
90125146    90    105.00     112      0.9375       0.828
```

ave_cost_category is the column I need to compute (it is currently null). I have ave_cost data in the table.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The sample data you posted has the ave_cost and ave_cost_category.

Comment: For cat 90, shouldn't the average be (351.20+105.00) / (439+112) = 0.828 ??

Comment: @ken - ave_cost_category is currently null. That's just example data I manually calculated.  

@marc - You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to calculate the average cost per category, and update your table from that:

```
;WITH CatCost AS
(
    SELECT
       Category,
       SUM(Cost) / (1.0 * SUM(Num)) 'AvgCostCat'
    FROM
       dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY
       Category
)
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ave_cost_category = cc.AvgCostCat
FROM CatCost
WHERE dbo.YourTable.Category = cc.Category
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
   ave_cost=cost/num,
   ave_cost_category=t1.ave_cost_category
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT category,avg(ave_cost) as ave_cost_category
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY category
) t1 on MyTable.category = t1.category
```

The inner query in the JOIN calculates the average cost across the entire category.

Comment: Taking the mean of the average costs won't work. The sum needs to be weighted according to how big `num` is. Plus you are using the value from a column that hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: This produces the table that the OP supplied.

Comment: True - I doubt they want the mean of the means though. And what about the second point? You are selecting `avg(ave_cost)` to populate `ave_cost_category` but also changing the value of `ave_cost` straight away afterwards.

Comment: @martin - My mistake, you're right, I don't want the mean of means. I've updated the question and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS c,
                SUM(num)  OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS n,
                *
         FROM   yourtable)
UPDATE t
SET    ave_cost = cost / num,
       ave_cost_category = c / n
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating both as computed columns in the table.

```
create function dbo.fnAveCostCat(@category int)
returns decimal(10,3)
as
begin
    declare @ave decimal(10,3)
    select @ave = AVG(t.cost/t.num)
        from YourTable t
        where t.category = @category
    return @ave
end
go

alter table YourTable
    add ave_cost as cost/num,
        ave_cost_category as dbo.fnAveCostCat(category)
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
 UPDATE yourTable SET ave_cost_category = x.avgcost FROM 
    yourTable inner JOIN (SELECT category, AVG(ave_cost) AS avgcost 
FROM yourTable GROUP BY category) x
    ON yourTable.category = x.category
```

Answer (score -1):

to update your average cost, try

```
update mytable set ave_cost = cost / num;
```

for the average cost per category, i'm not sure this will work on sql server, but you can try :

```
update mytable set ave_cost_category = average
from mytable
inner join (
    select category, avg(ave_cost) as average
    from mytable
    group by category
) as averages on table.category = averages.category
```